# Hang alignment in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, horizontal-alignment, indentation

My problem is rather simple but I wasn't able to find a satisfactory answer after some searching on the web and here.

I'm trying to build a bibliography manually and would like to modify the 'hangindent' of the bibliography, here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twopage,openright]{book}
\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{ME00}
\setlength{\itemindent}{.22cm}
\setlength{\labelwidth}{1.5cm} 
\bibitem[Ada75]{Ada75}Robert A. \textsc{Adams}, {Sobolev Spaces}, Academic Press, 1975.
\bibitem[Ber77]{Ber77}Melvin S. \textsc{Berger}, {Nonlinearity and Functional Analysis}, Academic Press, 1977.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

The `itemindent` and `labelwidth` are set such that the label is aligned with respect to the header (`itemindent`) and such that 'Robert' is aligned with 'Melvin' etc. (`labelwidth`).

When compiling this, I get the '-demic Press, 1977' of the second entry on a second line with a left offset with respect to 'Melvin'. How can I adjust this without changing the position of the label? (either aligning the hang to 'Melvin' or even adding a right offset)

My only requirement is that I'd rather not use either bibtex or natbib.

Thanks a lot! (and apologies if this is completely trivial)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `enumitem` package and redefine the `thebibliography` environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,openright]{book}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
 {%
  \chapter*{\bibname}%
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{\@biblabel{#1}}%
  \begin{enumerate}[
    leftmargin=!,
    labelwidth=\dimen0,
    align=left,
    before={\@openbib@code
            \sloppy
            \clubpenalty 4000 \@clubpenalty\clubpenalty
            \widowpenalty 4000
            \sfcode `\.\@m}
  ]%
 }
{%
 \def\@noitemerr{\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
 \end{enumerate}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{Ada75}
\bibitem[Ada75]{Ada75}Robert A. \textsc{Adams}, {Sobolev Spaces}, Academic Press, 1975.
\bibitem[Ber77]{Ber77}Melvin S. \textsc{Berger}, {Nonlinearity and Functional Analysis}, Academic Press, 1977.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

The argument to `thebibliography` should be the widest label, that you can set when the list of items is complete. This is better than computing by thumb the width.

Comment: thanks a lot for your prompt answer! I have two questions relative to your solution: 1) can you change the offset if you want to add a right indent to the second line? 2) I understand that the argument of `thebibliography` should be the widest label but how do you do that if you have, say, 200 entries in your bibliography? is there an automated way of finding your longest label? Thanks!

Comment: oops found the answer of the first question after checking the manual of `enumitem`: option `itemindent`. And it appears that for the second question, a 'good guess' is ok. thanks!